# Retina asset for list-style-image

Tags: css, retina-display

Does anyone know a great way to have a custom list-stlye-image for retina displays? The usual background-size trick in a media query doesn't work for list-style-image.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The best way to achieve this is to not use the list-style-image, but instead set a background-image for each li element in the list.

This way you can use the usual background-size tricks to allow for retina displays.

Comment: Hmmm... Not ideal, but makes sense. Didn't even think of that, thanks. I'll do just that.

Comment: Background images generally don't print though.

Comment: @Winston Normally print styles are supposed to be really stripped down, so I don't think that's a big trade off